# How to simultaneously iterate each_value on two similar arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays

In this case, both `locales` and `aliases` share the same structure and so I iterate them in the same way changing only its name.

```
if yml_site['locales'].present? 
     yml_site['locales'].each_value do |yml_locale|
          site = Site.find_or_create_by_domain(
               locale: yml_locale['locale'],
               domain: yml_locale['domain'],
               title: yml_locale['title'],
               parent: yml_site['domain'],
     end
end
if  yml_site['aliases'].present?
     yml_site['aliases'].each_value do |yml_alias|
          site = Site.find_or_create_by_domain(
               locale: yml_alias['locale'],
               domain: yml_alias['domain'],
               title: yml_alias['title'],
               parent: yml_alias['domain'],
     end
end
end
```

I was thinking to simplify this code with something like `[yml_site['locales'],yml_site['aliases']].each.each_value` but obviusly its not working. Any idea how can I iterate both `yml_site['locales']` and `yml_site['aliases']` on the same query ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
(yml_site['locales'] + yml_site['aliases']).each_value do |yml_locale|
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way is to push the iteration block to a common method and access it by method calls.

Other alternative, 
Just perform array addition,

```
x1 = [1,2,3]
x2 = [3,4,5]

x1 + x2, and then perform iteration as done for array.
```

To execute the operation in parallel, you can use

```
x1.zip(x2).each do |u,v|
  p u
  p v
  #perform find_or_create operation
end
```